# Android: How to make a canvas on only part of the screen dynamically?

Tags: android, canvas, layout

In android, how can I make a drawable canvas appear on only part of the screen when a user does an action?

My end-goal is to dynamically insert into the layout a bar that, when the user touches it, a particular text will be drawn on the bar.

I've searched, and I've only seen ways where a canvas is handled as a layout itself; not as a View that can be added to an activity. And my understanding is that to make it only part of the screen, I'd somehow have to handle it as a View that can be added to a layout. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For creating a canvas create the custom view like as below:

```
public class CanvasView extends View {

public int width;
public int height;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Path mPath;
Context context;
private Paint mPaint;
private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOLERANCE = 5;

public CanvasView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(c, attrs);
    context = c;

    // we set a new Path
    mPath = new Path();

    // and we set a new Paint with the desired attributes
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    // your Canvas will draw onto the defined Bitmap
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}

// override onDraw
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // draw the mPath with the mPaint on the canvas when onDraw
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}

// when ACTION_DOWN start touch according to the x,y values
private void startTouch(float x, float y) {
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

// when ACTION_MOVE move touch according to the x,y values
private void moveTouch(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOLERANCE || dy >= TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

public void clearCanvas() {
    mPath.reset();
    invalidate();
}

// when ACTION_UP stop touch
private void upTouch() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
}

//override the onTouchEvent
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startTouch(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            moveTouch(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upTouch();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

After that use this canvasView into the xml file:

```
<com.example.canvasdemo.CanvasView
    android:id="@+id/signature_canvas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
```

And last into your main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnClear;
private CanvasView customCanvas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    customCanvas = (CanvasView) findViewById(R.id.signature_canvas);
    btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


    btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            customCanvas.clearCanvas(); // to clear canvas
        }
    });


}
```

[image: example picture]

Comment: I don't think this exactly answers the question, since I was asking about making a canvas on only part of the screen. Regardless, I think I can figure out making it take up part of the screen using fragments. The bigger problem is that your solution doesn't seem to work at all for some reason. App crashes as soon as it's launched.

Comment: EDIT: My bad. I was entering the path wrong in the layout file.